# Behat is not displaying the regular expressions when running a new test

Tags: behat, web-testing

I have a problem with Behat, if I run a new test, it does not print the regular expressions. Is there a solution to this problem ? I googled it but I did not find an answer.

Note: I installed Behat using the git method. I think this might have something to do with it because it installed differently then the composer method (it put the files in a Behat folder and it installed some default tests). Yesterday I used the composer method and everything worked fine.